# × TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')

Tags: reactjs, api, request

I didn't understand why I got this error **TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')**, it's a very simple feature. I hope that someone could help me.

This is my code, and I can't map the object from the API request.
For privacy, I modified the key of the API request.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Featured() {

    const [featured, setFeatured] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://api.rawg.io/api/games?dates=2021-01-01,2021-12-31&ordering=-rating&key=1234')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.results.slice(0, 4));
            setFeatured(data.results.slice(0, 4));
        });
    }, []);


    return (
        <div className="container mt-5">
            <div className="row">
                {featured.map((el) => {
                    return (
                        <div>{el.name}</div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is because you started your data out as `null`. On initial render before the api has a chance to come back your `featured` array is actual null and you cannot call `.map` on null. Instead you can either start the data off as an empty array like so

`const [featured, setFeatured] = useState([]);`

Or you can have a check in your render to make sure its no longer `null` which will be the case after the api comes back with a response.

Comment: right!! Many thanks

Comment: Just wondering, I see a lot of tutorials using `null` as the initial state when using fetch API. But this will result in the `TypeError` above. No idea why they put it as `null`
(Ex link: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/fetch-data-react/)

Comment: my hunch is because in the event when you wanna have some conditional logic, it's easier to simply write `if(data)` vs `if(data.length)`. It's a small difference, but might be the reason

Answer (score -1):

```
{featured &&
 featured.map((el) => {
    return (
       <div>{el.name}</div>
    )
})}
```